# Slick.js arrows are not working in all tabs

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I'm using multiple tabs with multiple slick.js carousel.

Carousels are working good but prev and next arrows of carousels are not working except last one.

This is my carousel code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.services__slider').slick({
        infinite: true,
        prevArrow: '.arrow-prev',
        nextArrow: '.arrow-next',
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    });
})
```

And i'm using code in below for see to needed carousel in needed tab.

```
 $('.services__slider').slick('setPosition', 0);
```

My question is why every prev and next button is not working except last one?